# Memory issue with matlab runtime applet combined with java virtual machine and excel

Tags: java, excel, matlab, vba, memory

When I'm working with a specific workbook in excel, which my colleagues are running as well without problems, it calls a matlab runtime applet that is driven by a java virtual machine. When it attemps to run the program I get this error message:

[image: Error image]

And these are my java settings:

[image: JRE Settings]

I found a thread that addressed a similar looking problem where the solution was to change the java runtime parameters (as you can see on the second image) to allow for more memory. It did not work in my computer.

Since it's working on my colleagues computers, I started to figure what relevant differences are between my computer and there computers and the only differences I could find is that they have a licenced Matlab full set up on there computers and I don't. Except for this Matlab runtime I have. Which is the program causing the error, they use the same applet, but do not get this error.

We all have 32GB RAM and 32 bit OS.

One of my colleagues encounters the same error from time to time, but not always, he also does not have the full Matlab on his machine, like me. Two other coworkers who do have the full Matlab, never encounter the error.

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance and I hope you are all having a great newyear.

Comment: Have you tried to restart matlab after updating the maximum allowed memory for java? Also, you can try to do this from matlab as well. Go to preferences->MATLAB->General->Java Heap Memory and pull up that parameter. Then restart matlab.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment Patrik. I dont have Matlab, I just have the "Matlab applet" a.k.a. "Matlab Runtime" which is used to support this workbook and I'm being told I don't need Matlab to be able to run the Matlab Runtime without problems

Comment: I see, I have never worked with matlab applet, but you have tried to increase Xmx then? What did you set it too? Normally these kinds of applications have a .init file or something similar. Have you tried to increase Xmx directly in that file?

Comment: no I haven't tried that .. let me check that out, thanks

Comment: I cant link any init file to these applets. They seem to be stand alone .exe files. I've tried all kinds of combinations of Xmx, e.g. put it to the same as my colleagues have it, nothing works. One more piece of info that could help, is that I have to use a MCRInstaller before a custom Matlab applet can be used, if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: and I can actually run the applets without problems if I run them by them selfes, i.e. not through the excel macro